# doing something before default event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some plugin. In that

```
<button class="datepicker-button">&nbsp;</button>
```

There is some click event handler for this class datepicker-button in the plugin library.

I need some manual operations before triggering the default handler specified in the library.

Something like this:

```
$(".datepicker-button").on("click",function(){
    // some operations written by me
    // then do operations specified by the library
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to do something before click?

Comment: Why don't you just go into the code of the plugin and modify it there?  Or you could even delete the plugin's event handler and write your own after modifying some of the original plugin's code.

Comment: @Eclecticist Modifying a plugins code is never an answer. What if the plugin code is updated? You have to make your amendment again. If the code has been refactored a lot, it may not be possible to make the amendment you wanted.

Comment: I am using sap-ui5. Its huge library. I am unable to find where the handler is.

Comment: @EOF If the plugin doesn't give you any event to hook to before the `click` is raised, you could try using `mousedown`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I guess I hadn't considered that.  Noted.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. Nice Idea. I will definitely check this.

Comment: You can `bind` another click event to your button before the plugin binding. This way it will trigger your event before the plugin's event

Comment: @EOF good news. I've added my comment as an answer for you then :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah Sure. You deserve drops of points. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the plugin doesn't give you any event to hook to before the `click` is raised, you could use `mousedown` instead:

```
$(".datepicker-button").on("mousedown", function(){
    // your operations...
});
```

The `click` event of the plugin will then be fired when the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot catch the event via jQuery is because the ui5 components use their own event bus.

Usually I'd say that this is a case for implementing your own ui5-control like

```
    sap.ui.commons.DatePicker.extend("your.custom.control", { 
    // your code  
    }
```

you can easily get the coding of the comp you want to extend by getting it out of your browser via firebug or whateverbrowseryoureusing-developer tools. if you launch your app with the parameter sap-ui-debug=true you will not get the minified versions.
The files you're looking for will be called DatePicker-dbg.js and DatePickerRenderer-dbg.js.

Cheers
Michael